# Auto Completing Textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, visual-studio

I have a textbox in my winform. I want to autocomplete it with mobile number from a customer table. I have written the code but its not auto completing.

```
   string CS = "data source=.; database=BillingSoftware; user id=sa; Password=9495640";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Phone FROM Customers", con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        AutoCompleteStringCollection CustomerPhone = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            CustomerPhone.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
        }
        txt_customerPOS.AutoCompleteCustomSource = CustomerPhone;
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check rdr.Read() whether you have data are not?

or call "Phone" column name

or call rdr["Phone"].ToString()